# Find out which part of the given sentence has an error?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, expressions

(a) I could not put up in a hotel/ (b) because the boarding and lodging charges/ (c) were exorbitant.

So, the given answer is option (a), but I'm confused whether it is due to the preposition "in" (I guess it should be "at") or due to the phrase' put up in a hotel'

Comment: I don't find an obvious error here. But that use of _put up_ is old-fashioned ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_up#Verb) calls it "archaic"), and "boarding and lodging charges" is tautologous in modern English.

Comment: If word substitutions are permitted, then "I could not *stay* in a hotel" would be the natural way to phrase the idea. (Actually, "stay *at*" sounds better to my American ears.)

Comment: No one says: boarding and lodging charges for a  hotel.

Comment: @Lambie - yes. If you're boarded, then you are by definition lodged.

Comment: @ColinFine - I don't trust Wiktionary any further than I can throw it.

Comment: Anyway, charges at a hotel are assumed to be for board and lodging unless specified otherwise.

Comment: ***boarding and lodging*** isn't very idiomatic. We normally refer to *[the price of] [**price of board and lodging***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=price+of+boarding+and+lodging%2Cprice+of+board+and+lodgings%2Cprice+of+board+and+lodging&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: In Kausani we put up in a hotel with idyllic views" (2019); "We put up in a hotel near. the Ajanta caves." (2021). "“We put up in a hotel, much to K's disgust" - 'K' is Alfred J Kinsey (1935 account, so maybe a _little_ old-fashioned). To put up in or at a hotel is perfectly normal UK English, if -- slightly -- formal and possibly a bit middle and upper class. No at all 'archaic'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "put up" is kind of old fashioned. It means to be placed in accomodation. So, it is not something you can do to or for yourself. Somebody else must do it for you.

- The hotel manager agreed to put me up in his hotel.

It means the hotel manager agreed to let me use one of the rooms in his hotel.

You could change it to "be put up" to make it a passive action.

- (a) I could not *be* put up in a hotel/ (b) because the boarding and lodging charges/ (c) were exorbitant.

Alternatively you could replace "put up" with some other verb such as "stay" or "lodge" or some such. These would be active verbs that you can do yourself.

Comment: I would not say that transitive _put up_ is particularly old-fashioned - though I wouldn't use it of paid accommodation, as in a hotel. But there is an **intransitive** use which fits the OP's sentence exactly, which I would call old-fashioned (see sense 16 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_up#Verb))

Comment: @ColinFine I'd call the intransitive use a little old-fashioned, no more than that.

Comment: Considering tht the source calls it "archaic" I think old-fashioned is not unkind. The only place I have seen the term used in that way is in novels by Mark Twain and Charles Dickens.

Comment: @BillOnne - it's current in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey as a native AmE speaker, I found it immediately jarring to use "put up" in that way; perhaps the original question was only considering American English (or the asker was unaware of the difference)